# print superClass arraylist with subClass toString - java

Tags: java

I have a toString in the superclass and a toString in the subclass. I want to display things in an ArrayList of superclass, but with the toString of the subclass. For example:

```java
public class SuperClass{
    // field
    String name;
    // methods 
    public SuperClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name;
    }
}
```

Then I have a subclass

```java
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    // field 
    private int age;
    // methods
    public SubClass(String name, int age) {
        super(name);
        this.age = age;
    }
    @override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name +
               "\nAge: " + age;
    }
}
```

I want to display this superclass in the class MyList with the toString of the subclass. **Is this possible?**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyList {
    protected ArrayList<SuperClass> list = new ArrayList<>(); // display with Name and Age

    public void userInput() {
        // user inputting
        SubClass sub1 = new SubClass("Joe Black", 21);
        SubClass sub2 = new SubClass("Jane Black", 20);
        SuperClass sup1 = new SuperClass("Adam");
        list.add(sub1);
        list.add(sub2);
        list.add(sup1);
    }

    public void print() {
        for (SuperClass e : list) {
            System.out.println(e); // uses print methods of SuperClass or SubClass
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyList theList = new MyList();
        theList.userInput();
        theList.print();
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
$ javac SubClass.java SuperClass.java MyList.java
$ java -cp . MyList                              
Name: Joe Black
Age: 21
Name: Jane Black
Age: 20
Name: Adam
$
```

Additionally, I have multiple subclasses.

the problem I have now is that it only prints the Name
actual output:

```
$ javac SubClass.java SuperClass.java MyList.java
$ java -cp . MyList                              
Name: Joe Black
Name: Jane Black
Name: Adam
```

Comment: Which part of this is not working?

Comment: like it should print the name and the age, but it only prints the name right now. It is not using the toString of subClass

Comment: Your code works fine for me on [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/snv)

Comment: it is not working for me, the post is edit by someone

Comment: Please post compilable code. The code as shown doesn't compile, as `@override` is not a valid annotation (that would be `@Override`). If I correct that error in your code, it runs just fine and produces your expected output. My guess is that because it doesn't compile, you're using an older version of the class.

Comment: worksforme - after fixing the typo (noticed by @MarkRotteveel) in the override annotation

Answer (score -1):

For convenience I put all classes into one file:

*MyList.java*

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MyList {
    protected ArrayList<SuperClass> list = new ArrayList<>(); // display with Name and Age
    public void userInput() {
        // user inputting
        SubClass sub1 = new SubClass("Joe Black", 21);
        SubClass sub2 = new SubClass("Jane Black", 20);
        SuperClass sup1 = new SuperClass("Adam");
        list.add(sub1);
        list.add(sub2);
        list.add(sup1);
    }
    public void print() {
        for (SuperClass e : list) {
            if (e.getClass() == SuperClass.class)
            {
                // SuperClass has no attribute age. Therefore, create temporary SubClass instance
                SubClass s = new SubClass(e.name, 0);
                e = s;
            }
            System.out.println(e); // uses .toString of corresponding class 
        }
    }    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyList theList = new MyList();
        theList.userInput();
        theList.print();
    }
}

class SuperClass {
        // field
    String name;
    // methods 
    public SuperClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name;
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
        // field 
    private int age;
    // methods
    public SubClass(String name, int age) {
        super(name);
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name +
               "  Age: " + age;
    }
}
```

SuperClass has no attribute `age`. Therefore, the `print` method uses an exact class check and creates a temporary SubClass instance in order to use its `toString` method.

This produces the following output.

```
$ javac MyList.java
$ java MyList      
Name: Joe Black  Age: 21
Name: Jane Black  Age: 20
Name: Adam  Age: 0
$
```

Please note that there where a new instance of SubClass is generated in `MyList.print` it would also to be possible to modify the output in other ways, e.g. print "Name: Adam  Age: -". The MyList class can handle the SuperClass instance there as you like.

Comment: sorry, but this is utterly wrong:  there is no need whatsoever to type-cast before printing, even less so to create a new instance. And you forgot the Override annotation (which your IDE should have warned you about)

Comment: @kleopatra You certainly have interpreted the question in a different way than I do. The author wants a very particular, unusual thing to which I offer a possible solution. "print superClass arraylist with subClass toString". Feel free to offer another solution. I might have misinterpreted the question.